# dequeuing and enqueuing minified js files in childtheme wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, enqueue

I'm trying to dequeue a minified js file from wordpress parent theme.
Can't seem to work out how to dequeue and then enqueue my own custom js file from child theme.

Here is my code:

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_remove_scripts', 20 );

    function my_remove_scripts(){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'custom' );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_scripts');

    function my_add_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script('custom-child', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom'.$js_minify_prefix.'.js', array('jquery'), THEME_VERSION, true);
    }
```

The script in the parent theme is enqueued like this:

```
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom'.$js_minify_prefix.'.js', array('jquery'), THEME_VERSION, true);
```

Is there something I'm missing in the code or is there a special way of dequeueing/enqueueing minified scripts?
Any help would be appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just one mistake in your code. You are dequeuing and then enqueuing the same file.

Use this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_remove_scripts', 20 );

function my_remove_scripts(){
wp_dequeue_script( 'custom' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_scripts');

function my_add_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_script('custom-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
}
```

**get_stylesheet_directory_uri()** is the key here. It returns the path of the child theme. Also, I have removed the $js_minify_prefix variable from the code as it is not required.

Comment: Wow thank you so very much! not sure how I didn't pick that! you're the best!